# When does an expired domain become available for others to register?

Tags: domains, domain-registration, domain-registrar, registration, icann

I'm trying to purchase a domain name that was registered and apparently already expired. This is its status:

```
Status: clientHold http://www.icann.org/epp#clientHold
Status: clientTransferProhibited http://www.icann.org/epp#clientTransferProhibited
Status: redemptionPeriod http://www.icann.org/epp#redemptionPeriod
Updated Date: 14-oct-2015
Creation Date: 01-sep-2014
Expiration Date: 01-sep-2015
```

From what I'm seeing from ICANN policies, it should already be available to be registered by third parties, but maybe I'm missing something. When will it become available for me to register it?

Comment: @gnat this is not about a company, it's about understanding ICANN procedures. I didn't even mention a company because it's irrelevant which registrar I'm interacting with.

Answer (score 6):

Domain has 30 days renewal from the date after it expired. Then redemption period activates for another 30 days.

After the redemption period, you'll be able to register domain again.

**Redemption period means this:**

This status code indicates that your registrar has asked the registry to delete your domain. Your domain will be held in this status for 30 days. After five calendar days following the end of the redemptionPeriod, your domain is purged from the registry database and becomes available for registration.

Comment: The grave period after redemption is actually 40 days for .com and it'll release to the public at the same time as it was registered, which is the most important factor. So its actually `70 days + 0-24hours`.

Comment: @SimonHayter ah! that makes sense, because this domain expired for more than 60 days and it's still pending.

Comment: Is there a good way to reserve the domain without having to hit refresh constantly on the 71st day?

Comment: if its a highly desirable domain manually trying will be hopeless, your have companies attempting to register hundreds of times per a second. You may need to pay a company to snatch it for you. Google it, there's many.

Comment: @SimonHayter I know there are many but they look so dodgy.

Comment: Not all are... some deal with the top companies in the world.

Comment: The domain in question still remains unavailable, after 74 days of expiration date.

Comment: @J.PabloFernández, were you able to pick this expired domain finally?

Comment: After how many days?